# How can I dump my DB with mysqldump and make it skip the table partition info?

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I have a production DB that I'm constantly dumping into my QA environment.
The production DB has a few tables that are partitioned. On my QA environment I have no need for those tables to be partitioned since I don't import all the live data.

I'd like to perform a mysqldump command that will output the tables' CREATE info *without* the partition statement (i.e. without "PARTITION BY ...").

Comment: Not sure if it works the same in Mysql, but in MariaDB 10.0.38 the partitions definition appears always commented inside /*...*/ , not using any particular flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found an elegant way to strip partitions.  I've been using the following bit of regex hackery:

```
perl -i -pe 's/^\/\*![0-9]* PARTITION BY.*$/;/' foo.sql

perl -i -pe 's/^.PARTITION.*ENGINE = .*$//' foo.sql
```

The first regex removes the opening PARTITION BY and replaces it with a semicolon to close off the preceeding CREATE TABLE.

The second regex removes all the partition declarations.

Answer (score 0):

You control which tables are dumped by either listing the tables explicitly or using `--ignore-table=` (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_ignore-table) -- whichever is easier.

I don't know of a way of having mysqldump infer which tables to ignore by their characteristics (such as being partitioned). You are best to be explicit with one of these two approaches.